# How to get the grandparent of the grandparent of a div in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a better way to get the parent of the parent of the parent... like 5 times?

So Instead of using this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

I could use something like this:

```
$(this).goBacktoNthParent(5);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### *Using the `:eq()` selector*

The `:eq()` selector allows you to target the element at the zero-based index of the set that was matched...

```
$(this).parents(':eq(4)')
```

**Note: use parent(s) selector**

Because the selector is zero based, we gave it one less than the number targeted.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pmMFv/

---

### *Using the `.eq()` method*

The `.eq()` method is effectively the same as its selector counterpart, allowing you to target the element at the zero-based index of the set that was matched...

```
$(this).parents().eq(4)
```

**Note: use parent(s) selector**

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pmMFv/2/

---

### *Using `parentNode` in a loop*

For greatest performance, we could use the `.parentNode` property of the element, and run it in a loop, updating a variable with the newest parent each time...

```
var el = this, i = 5;
while(i-- && (el = el.parentNode));

$(el)
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pmMFv/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create your own function:

```
function getNthParentOf(elem,i) {
    while(i>0) {
        elem = elem.parent();
        i--;
    }
    return elem;
}

var something = getNthParentOf($(this),5);
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are identifying markers on the parent element you want to get - such as an `id` or `class` you can use `$(this).closest("#grandparentElement")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) traversing function in conjunction with the `:nth()` selector.

So the result will be something like:

```
$(this).parents(':nth(5)'));
```

**Notice:** the `:nth()` index starts from 0 so for your case it should be:

```
$(this).parents(':nth(4)'));
```

Comment: Seems odd that this works, since the API docs have no mention of an `:nth` selector, only `:nth-child`. But I tested, and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this would be of any help.

try using .parentsUntil()

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/wLhcA/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try

```
var parentControl = $('#yourcontrol').parent();
var grandParent = parentControl.parent();
```